# iOS自作フレームワークでプッシュ通知を受け取りたい

Tags: ios

表題の通り、iOSの自作フレームワークでプッシュ通知の受信を実装したいと思っています。

そもそも実現できるかもハッキリとは分かりませんが、
アプリケーション側だとuser notifications frameworkを使用する事によって通知の受信ができることは知っており、フレームワーク側で受信する方法がどうにも見つかりません。

実現の可否・可能な場合はその方法等を教えていただけると幸いです。

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOSのフレームワークは最終的には何らかのアプリケーションに組み込まれ、１つのアプリケーションとして動作するわけですので、コードがどこに書いてあるかだけの違いなので、アプリケーションに書いていたものをフレームワーク側に記述するということは可能ではあります。

ただし、UserNotifications.frameworkの仕組み上、アプリケーションの作成者側で処理をハンドルする必要がどうしても出てくるので、フレームワーク側だけでそれらを扱うのはできなくはないですが、難しいです。

ですので、例えばチャットサポートを提供するHelpShiftのSDKなどは、返信をプッシュ通知で知らせる機能が提供されていますが、セットアップはアプリケーションのプログラマ側が行う仕組みになっていてある程度のコードを書く必要があります。

（参考） https://developers.helpshift.com/ios/notifications/#push-via-helpshift

なので、質問の回答として求めているものかどうかは自信がありませんが、フレームワーク側で簡単にできる部分と使う側で書く部分とを分けて考えるのが一般的な方法だと思います。